# How To Change Default Sub Form Of Access Navigation Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

i have created a Navigation form in Access with few buttons named "Item Description","Orders",,,,,, and "User's Login" respectively.i want to set last sub form(User's Login) as default form when i open it.how to do it? appreciate your help

Comment: Wekcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve your question (edit) and you will get helped!

Answer (score 0):

To set focus to a subform control use:

`Forms!Mainform!Subform1.Form!ControlName.SetFocus`

A good cheatsheet with how to refer to Form and Subform properties and controls:

http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm